# How to download jQuery compressed production?

Tags: jquery

When I try to download Jquery compressed production version there is no zip file downloaded. Here is the link: https://jquery.com/download/#jquery

Comment: There is no ZIP file to be downloaded. The links use the `download` attribute. In browsers which support it, it will ask you where to save the file. In browser that don't support the attribute, it opens the JS file directly. In that case you simply need to copy the content and save it to a JS file yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't download automatically, then you can just copy and paste it and save it as a .js file